# Regex - Getting data up until first occurrence of two different sequences

Tags: python, regex

I'm given a string that contains valid codes and sometimes invalid codes.  Each string is structured with `...valid for 111, 333, 555`.  The string could end with a period or include one of the following `(except  3331, 3332, 5554).`, `except 3331, 5555.`, or `except(3331, 5554).` within the list of valid codes. Each sentence could also have some additional notes that aren't relevant, but could hold digits.

Example: `... 111, 222, 333 (except 3331, 3332, 3339), 444, 555, 77781, and 89. Note: Look up doc 432`

I need to parse the string to get a list of valid digit codes as well as a list of exceptions.  I've gotten everything up until a period with `^[^.]+` and everything up until the word except with `.+?(?=except)`, but cannot figure out how to make the first pass to get the valid codes before `.` or `except` which ever comes first.

I'm hoping to just break up the sentence in this pass, if I'm able to get the digits with one regex per valid and invalid codes that would be ideal.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you realize that your example uses the word `excluding` rather than `except`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

text = "Example: ... valid for 111, 222, 333 (except 3331, 3332, 3339), 444, 555, 77781, and 89. Note: Look up doc 432"

m = re.search(r'valid for ([^.]+)\.', text) #everything between  'valid for ' and first '.'
text1 = m.group(1)
valid_numbers = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', text1) # first find all numbers
m = re.search(r'except([^.)]*)[.)]', text) # everything between 'except' and either ')' or '.'
text2 = m.group(1)
except_numbers = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', text2) # find the "except" numbers
# remove the "except" numbers from valid_numbers
for i in range(len(valid_numbers) - 1, -1, -1):
    if valid_numbers[i] in except_numbers:
        del[valid_numbers[i]]
print(valid_numbers)
print(except_numbers)
```

Prints:

```
['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '77781', '89']
['3331', '3332', '3339']
```

[See demo](https://ideone.com/Rl132t)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I knew this is was possible with many regex calls and loops, but wanted the cleanest version.  This was a much more direct approach.  Thanks again.